# ASP.NET WEB API JSON Polymorphism

Tags: json

JSON deserialization not working for polymorphic attribute behavior-

Sample code -
--MODEL

```
public class A
{
    public string a_property { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string b_property { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public A a { get; set; }
}
```

--API

```
public partial class TestController : ApiBaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetC()
    {
        return Ok<C>(new C(){a = new B(){a_property="test", b_property ="test1"}});
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveC(C c)
    {
        return Ok<C>(c);
    }
}
```

--Web Route config

```
Config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling =     TypeNameHandling.Objects;
Config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
Config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

From UI GetC API is called the object returned is C with attribute a of type B. It does have the type detail i.e. [$type A, assembly name]. When the same JSON is posted from client to call SaveC API the deserialized JSON is of type C but the attribute a is of type A instead of B. 
I have searched the web but with no help, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.net deserializer is just respecting your model, if you want specify the heritage level for your entity, you need to create a custom converter or you can work with an interface and just use a jsonconvert attribute.

Comment: Below is the JSON that is posted to the SaveC API. By setting Type handler name to TypeNameHandling.Objects the JSON contains the $type attribute which has the class information. What's the purpose of the $type attribute if the deserializer does not interpret it and convert it without creating the custom conversion?                  {
 "$id":"1",
 "$type":"Test.C, TestProject",
 "a":
  {
   "$id":"2",
   "$type":"Test.B, TestProject",
   "b_property":"test1",
   "a_property":"test"
  },
 "$promise":{},
 "$resolved":true
    }